# Download one item at a time from AsyncTask

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a fragment with `GridView` with `ImageViews` as items. The amount cells is around 25.

For every Image I have a server request by Id. So its 25 server requests. Takes 2-3 seconds.

**How can I receive one image at a time and dynamically set it as content of cell?** And every cell, which doesn't have image yet should contain `ProgressBar`.

**What do I have now:** I'm trying to load items in `AsyncTask` and return `Bitmap` array back to UI thread. But I don't know how to do that for every Image. My `GridView` appears only after ALL images downloaded. And it should be visible first with 25 elements which contain `ProgressBars` and no Images.

---

**Code code**

fragment's `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    mItems = new Bitmap[dataChannelsList.size()];

    try {
    //starting AsyncTask
        mItems = new LoadImageAsyncTask(dataChannelsList).execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`LoadImageAsyncTask`:

```
private class LoadImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap[], Void, Bitmap[]> {
    private ArrayList<DataChannels> dataChannelsList;
    private Bitmap[] bitmapList;

    public LoadImageAsyncTask(ArrayList<DataChannels> dataChannelsList) {
        this.dataChannelsList = dataChannelsList;

        bitmapList = new Bitmap[dataChannelsList.size()];
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(Bitmap[]... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataChannelsList.size(); i++) {
            bitmapList[i] = getChannelImg(dataChannelsList.get(i).getId());
        }
        return bitmapList;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] param) {
        super.onPostExecute(param);
    }

    private Bitmap getChannelImg(String id) {
        ...returns Bitmap image by id
    }

}
```

`GridView` adapter:

```
    public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private Bitmap[] mItems;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, Bitmap[] items) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_channelIcon);
            viewHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_load_image);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // update the item view
        Bitmap item = mItems[position];

        //hide progress bar and bring image to top
        viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(item);
        return convertView;
    }

}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivIcon;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
}
```

Guys, I really need your help. *Tell if some more code or explanations needed.*

Comment: check out Picasso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330772/why-use-android-picasso-library-to-download-images, or at least review an open source solution like this to learn

Comment: You should call imageLoaderTask onGetView() method of adapter. Also your loader task download should be parameterized and called by adapter with your image_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `publishProgress()` for this to call `onProgressUpdate()`

So in your `for loop` something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataChannelsList.size(); i++) {
        // create a variable for the current bitmap
        Bitmap curBitmap = getChannelImg(dataChannelsList.get(i).getId()); 
        // add it to your list
        bitmapList[i] = curBitmap;
        // and pass it along
        publishProgress(curBitmap);
    }
```

then you will need to override `onProgressUpdate()` which is called by `publishProgress()`

```
@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap...progress) {
    /* add the bitmap to your list you're using for your adapter here
     * and call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter
    */
}
```

You then would need to change your asynctask to

```
private class LoadImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap[], Bitmap, Bitmap[]> {
```

You also don't want to call `.get()` on your `AsyncTask` because [it is a blocking call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425807/button-remains-pressed-while-the-asynctask-is-being-executed/17425875#17425875)

Something similar to this should give you what you want.

**Alternatives**

However, there are a lot of [libraries that can do the work for you and give you benefits](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46).

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    mItems = new Bitmap[dataChannelsList.size()];
    GridView grid=// declare your gridview;
GridViewAdapter adapter=new GridViewAdapter(activityname.this,mItems);
grid.setAdapter(adapter);

    try {
    //starting AsyncTask here

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and in the assynctask

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] param) {
        super.onPostExecute(param);
         adapter.notifydatasetchanged;

// adapter should be declared as class variable,so that it can be used here.or else pass adapter variable as actual parameter to assynctask constructor

    }
```

for progress bar I think what you are doing is correct
change your adapter class's

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 25;// the size you want
    }
```

inside getView method

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

int currentposition=position;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_channelIcon);
            viewHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_load_image);
           viewHolder.ivIcon.setTag(currentposition);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // update the item view
        Bitmap item = mItems[position];

        //hide progress bar and bring image to top

if(Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.ivIcon.getTag().toString())>mItems.size()){
        viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 viewHolder.ivIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else{
viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 viewHolder.ivIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
        viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(item);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: This can never work. Do not use .get() on an AsyncTask.

Comment: @greenapps pls check the code once again ok...and that's not my codeline.

Comment: Why did you remove the code to call the asynctask? Further this code does nothing with downloading all at once or one by one. So what are you solving?

Comment: @greenapps What do I have now: I'm trying to load items in AsyncTask and return Bitmap array back to UI thread. But I don't know how to do that for every Image. My GridView appears only after ALL images downloaded. And it should be visible first with 25 elements which contain ProgressBars and no Images.  this was the question and the above codelines need to be added in his existing code.he have code for download already pls read his question.I just gave him suggestion to how  to refresh his gridview after each image download and how to show progress bar in grids with no iimage.that's all

Comment: `But I don't know how to do that for every Image.`. Yes thats why i said that it was not gonna work, The answer of codeMagic shows how it can be done.